# Manually specify a tunnel gateway for an IPSec VPN Connection (ASA)

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

I have currently got several VPN's on-premise that are setup on the outside interface and using the default gateway on the interface as an originating source of the VPN tunnel.

Although the outside interface has been configured with a block of IP's - of which I would like a new VPN I am creating to originate from another IP.

I noticed there is a 'Tunnelled' option under the static routes section that allows you to set a default tunnel - although in my case I would like to have more than one origin for VPN's on the outside interface.

My question is - is it possible to have more than one originating source?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible on a Cisco ASA to originate a VPN tunnel from a source IP address other than itself.  This is possible on Cisco IOS and IOS-XE routers.

The `tunneled` keyword on a static router specifies that any traffic that arrives at the ASA inside of a tunnel and is successfully decrypted from the tunnel, shall use that static route in preference of others.  This is useful in a situation where you have a dedicated Remote Access VPN firewall, but your normal browsing firewall has some type of web-filtering services.  To get your VPN clients to terminate on the RA firewall, yet still go to the core and out the Web firewall, you would add the "tunneled" keyword to the 0.0.0.0/0 route on the RA firewall.